# class weblogic.management.WeblogicMBean not found

Tags: ant, junit, weblogic

I meet this problem when I try to run Junit test case in fork mode (starting each test in a separate JVM) using Build ant file.

> [junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weblogic/management/WebLogicMBean [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) [junit] at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
>   [junit] at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260) [junit]
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56) [junit]
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195) [junit] at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [junit] at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188) [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) [junit] at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) [junit]
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252) [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) [junit]
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) [junit] at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
>   [junit] at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260) [junit]
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56) [junit]
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195) [junit] at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [junit] at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188) [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) [junit] at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) [junit]
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252) [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) [junit]
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [junit] at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) [junit] at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
>   [junit] at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260) [junit]
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56) [junit]
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195) ....

I have the library weblogic.jar in my build library folders, which is set as classpath for the junit task. I look at this file and can't find the WeblogicMBean.class inside.

However, in Jdev, I can import `weblogic.management.WeblogicMBean` into my class if I set library reference to this weblogic.jar file and compile my class without problem.

Any suggestion of what really goes wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError usually means the **correct** version of the class was not found at **runtime**.

Since your compile is fine, does your CLASSPATH at compile time refer to the same jar as at runtime? 
Also check if there are multiple weblogic.jar in the runtime CLASSPATH for JUnit.

Whats your version of weblogic, the class is in the weblogic.jar for version 9 at least.